# How to solve: At least one of the arguments for '' cannot be marshaled by the runtime marshaler

Tags: c#, c++, com, activex, marshalling

I have a COM object written in C++ and a C# application using this ActiveX control.
The C++ code is compiling fine, without any warnings.
The C# application is generating several warnings like in the title.

I see all COM functions have a similar signature, they all expect a `int**` input parameter.
I assume this is the problem. Using Google I find posts suggesting it too.  I also find posts saying I can ignore these warnings. But because I also have access to the C++ code I would like to solve it.

This is my idl:

```cpp
[id(34), helpstring("method DrawRectangle")] HRESULT DrawRectangle([in]int** hdc, [in]float x, [in]float y, [in]int width, [in]int height, [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL* retVal);
```

This is the C++ function:

```cpp
STDMETHODIMP CShapeDrawingOptions::DrawRectangle(int** hdc, float x, float y, int width, int height, VARIANT_BOOL* retVal)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState())
    const auto dc = CDC::FromHandle(reinterpret_cast<HDC>(hdc));

    *retVal = this->DrawRectangleCore(dc, x, y, width, height);
    return S_OK;
}
```

This is how I call it in C#:

```cs
using(var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
    var retVal = shapeDrawingOptions.DrawRectangle(hdc, 40.0f, 40.0f, width - 80, height - 80);
    g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
    bmp.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

`GetHdc` is returning an IntPtr which is send to the COM function and should be marshaled to `int**`

It is all working. I just want to get rid of the compiler warnings.
The ActiveX control is distributed and other developers are getting these warnings, which is very sloppy.
I can make changes in the C++ and/or C# code.

Comment: Are you sure it is working? COM requires SAFEARRAY to marshal correctly.

Comment: The int** is also *int[].

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is working. In fact it is working for several years now. We have these warnings that long as well.  I just made a version with `int hdc` instead of `int** hdc` and when calling it like `g.GetHdc().ToInt32` in C# it seems to be working as well.  I'm not a C++ developer, just know some C# and I'm not sure if changing `int**` to `int` is a good idea.  Are their any drawbacks or is this a good change?

Comment: This doesn't look right. An input parameter of `int**` named `hdc` seems implausible

Comment: Lots of problems. int** is a funky definition for HDC which is just an opaque handle (=> size of a pointer). VARIANT_BOOL smells like COM Automation, but int** certainly doesn't . It looks like it works probably because you're running in-process...
Automation doesn't have the "pointer" data type, but try to replace `int**` by `INT_PTR` and tlbimp (with help from the midl compiler) should see it as a .NET Int64 (so both 32 and 64 pointer sizes will fit int), but it's still not an Automation-compatible interface.